# Is there a way to pass arguments with logical operators (!=, >,<) to a function?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

```
create_c <- function(df, line_number = NA, prior_trt, line_name, biomarker, ...) {
    
    if (!"data.frame" %in% class(df)) {
        stop("First input must be dataframe")
    }

    # handle extra arguments
    args <- enquos(...)
    names(args) <- tolower(names(args))

    # check for unknown argument - cols that do not exist in df
    check_args_exist(df, args)

    # argument to expression
    ex_args <- unname(imap(args, function(expr, name) quo(!!sym(name) == !!expr)))

    # special case arguments

    if (!missing(line_number)) {
        df <- df %>% filter(line_number %in% (!!line_number))

        if (!missing(prior_trt)) {
            df <- filter_arg(df. = df, arg = prior_trt, col = "prior_trt_", val = "y")
        }
    }

    if (!missing(biomarker)) {
        df <- filter_arg(df. = df, arg = biomarker, col = "has_", val = "positive")
    }

    if (!missing(line_name)) {
        ln <- list()
        if (!!str_detect(line_name[1], "or")) {
            line_name <- str_split(line_name, " or ", simplify = TRUE)
        }
        for (i in 1:length(line_name)) {
            ln[[i]] <- paste(tolower(sort(strsplit(line_name[i], "\\+")[[1]])), collapse = ",")
        }
        df <- df %>% filter(line_name %in% (ln))
    }

    df <- df %>%
        group_by(patient_id) %>%
        slice(which.min(line_number)) %>%
        ungroup()


    df <- df %>% filter(!!!ex_args)

    invisible(df)
}
```

I have this function where I am basically filtering various columns based on parameters users pass. I want the users to be able to pass logical operators like >,<, != for some of the parameters. Right now my function is not able to handle any other operators besides '='. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
create_c(df = bsl_all_nsclc,
      line_number > 2)

create_c(df, biomarker != "positive)
```

Error in tolower(arg) : object 'biomarker' not found

Comment: Maybe you can switch to giving the filter arguments as strings like `"biomarker != 'positive'"` and then use `eval(parse(text=...))`

Comment: @Jonas Doing this via strings is unnecessary in R, and is in fact an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly there is a way: operators are regular functions in R, you can pass them around like any other function.

The only complication is that the operators are *non-syntactic names* so you can’t just pass them “as is”, this would confuse the parser. Instead, you need to wrap them in backticks, to make their use syntactically valid where a name would be expected:

```
filter_something = function (value, op) {
    op(value, 13)
}


filter_something(cars$speed, `>`)
filter_something(cars$speed, `<`)
filter_something(cars$speed, `==`)
```

And since R also supports non-standard evaluation of function arguments, you can also pass *unevaluated expressions* — this gets slightly more complicated, since you’d want to evaluate them in the *correct context*. ‘rlang’/‘dplyr’ uses [data masking](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/eval_tidy.html) for this.

How exactly you need to apply this depends entirely on the context in which the expression is to be used. In many cases, you can simply dispatch them to the corresponding ‘dplyr’ functions, e.g.

```
filter_something2 = function (.data, expr) {
    .data %>%
        filter({{expr}})
}

filter_something2(cars, speed < 13)
```

The “secret sauce” here is the `{{…}}` syntax. This works because `filter` from ‘dplyr’ accepts unevaluated arguments and handles `{{expr}}` specially by transforming it into (effectively) `!! enexpr(expr)`. That is: `expr` is first “defused”: it is explicitly marked as unevaluated, and the name `expr` is replaced by the unevaluated expression it binds to (`speed < 13` in the above). Next, this unevaluated expression is *unquoted*. That is, the wrapper is “peeled off” from the expression, and that unevaluated *expression itself* is handled inside `filter` as if it were passed as `filter(.data, speed < 13)`. In other words: the name `expr` is substituted with the `speed < 13` in the call expression.

For a more thorough explanation, please refer to the [*Programming with dplyr*](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette.